# Excel VBA - Application.Match not working (IsInArray)

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have written my first proper Excel script but the last step seems not to be working. I am including the whole code with comments but the important short block is the last block of code before End, For loop just after this comment:

`'-------------------- perform search and write into destination`

I'm also thinking that "ByVal" in my function definition also might have something to do with the problem?

```
'====================================================================
'This proceedure retrieves 'Amount Spent' per campaign form sheets
'labeled 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', ... and writes them onto
'rawData' Sheet.

'From there, data gets updated in the pivot tables on sheets 'search',
'gdn', 'youtube'.
'====================================================================

Public Month As String

Private SourceSheet As Worksheet
Private CampaignsCount As Integer
Private arrCampaignsAmounts() As Variant
Private StringsCount As Long
Private arrStrings() As Variant
Private strBaba As String


Public Function IsInArray(ByVal stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function


Public Sub stringComparison()

Call OptimizeCode_Begin


'------------------- get user input, which month (sheet) are we working on

    ChooseMonthUserform.Show
    Set SourceSheet = Worksheets(Month)

        With SourceSheet

            CampaignsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F:F")) - 1
            ReDim arrCampaignsAmounts(1 To CampaignsCount, 1 To 2)


'------------------- read Campaigns/Amounts from .csv, write into an array

            For i = 1 To CampaignsCount
                k = 6
                For j = 1 To 2
                    arrCampaignsAmounts(i, j) = .Cells(i + 11, k).Value
                        k = 9

                Next j
            Next i

        End With



'-------------------- load strings to search for into another array

   Set SourceSheet = Sheet2

        With SourceSheet

            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            StringsCount = (lastrow - 1) / 12

            ReDim arrStrings(1 To StringsCount, 1 To 2)

            k = 1

                For i = 1 To StringsCount
                        arrStrings(i, 1) = .Range("A" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("D" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("E" & i + k).Value
                        arrStrings(i, 2) = .Range("A" & i + k).Row

                            k = k + 11
                Next i

        'Sheet11.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrStrings, 1), UBound(arrStrings, 2)) = _
        'arrStrings



'-------------------- perform search and write into destination

            For i = 1 To UBound(arrStrings)
                If IsInArray(arrStrings(i, 1), arrCampaignsAmounts) = True Then
                    SourceSheet.Range("H" & arrStrings(i, 2)) = arrCampaignsAmounts(i, 2)
                Else
                End If
            Next i

        End With



    '===============================================================================
    'TO DO:

    '> search for strings and write 'Amounts' back into 'rawData'
    '> redesign the second array so that it takes into account which month
    '> it is, which row to start from (jan - row #2, feb - row#3, mar - row #4, ...)
    '> try and read into arrays all at once without loops
'===============================================================================


    Call OptimizeCode_End
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your lookup array has two columns, Match won't work with that.  Try VLookUp instead

Answer (score 0):

Add excel Index() function to retrieve the desired column array of multi dimensioned array.

```
IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, Application.Index(arr, , 2), 0))
```